# Bad Use of Null Coalescing Operator?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

```
myFoo = myFoo ?? new Foo();
```

instead of

```
if (myFoo == null) myFoo = new Foo();
```

Am I correct in thinking that the first line of code will always perform an assignment? Also, is this a bad use of the null-coalescing operator?

Comment: You make a convincing argument for the `??=` operator :)

Comment: @PavelMinaev in this case, is that not identical to the `||=` operator? It would have to replace a call `if (!isset(myFoo)) myFoo = new Foo();` to warrant its own operator

Comment: It's not identical, since `||` requires a Boolean value.

Comment: (Are you confusing this with PHP, by chance? Note that the question is tagged C#.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I compared the CIL of the generated code (making sure to do a Release build - with Optimize Code checked in the Project Properties, which corresponds to the `/optimize` switch on `csc.exe`). This is what I got (using VS 2008 - note that `Foo.MaybeFoo()` is a method that sometimes returns `null`, sometimes a `Foo`)

`GetFooWithIf`:

```
  IL_0000:  call       class Application3.Foo Application3.Foo::MaybeFoo()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  brtrue.s   IL_000f
  IL_0009:  newobj     instance void Application3.Foo::.ctor()
  IL_000e:  stloc.0
  IL_000f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0010:  ret
```

`GetFooWithCoalescingOperator`:

```
  IL_0000:  call       class Application3.Foo Application3.Foo::MaybeFoo()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  dup
  IL_0008:  brtrue.s   IL_0010
  IL_000a:  pop
  IL_000b:  newobj     instance void Application3.Foo::.ctor()
  IL_0010:  stloc.0
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  ret
```

Thus, the same except for an extra top-of-stack-duplication and pop. If this can be made to make a measurable performance difference, I will purchase a hat specifically for the purpose of eating it; therefore, go with the one that you feel offers better readability.

(edit) oh, and the JITter might be clever enough to get rid of even that difference!

Comment: Is this with `csc.exe /optimize+`?

Comment: I don't know how big Foo really is. Does it's size affect time to run dup & pop?

Comment: @Gary in the code here, it was a `class`, and object references are all the same size. With a `struct` you would get different code, I'm pretty sure. But we are advised to keep `struct`s to a maximum of 16 bytes, so not too much worse.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this a bad use of the null-coalescing operator. When reading the code, it is as short and concise as possible, and the intent of the code is obvious.

It is correct that using the null-coalescing operator like this, you will always get an assignment, but I would not worry about that. (And if it *really* turns out to be a performance issue, you already know how to fix it).

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in that the first line will always make an assignment. I would not worry about that unless the code is executed very often.

Comment: What should stop the compiler from optimizing it away?

Comment: @Timbo: I am not too knowledgeable about which optimizations the compiler may or may not do, but I make the assumption that `myFoo` will be used elsewhere in the code and that this would prevent the compiler from optimizing it away. If it is not used elsewhere, it's a different story.